# Calling procedure using linq c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, entity-framework-migrations

I use this code here to get data from procedure

```
string msg = "";
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=PORT))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID))); User Id=Id;Password=Password");

try
{
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "my procedure";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("WGRP_COMP_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("WSTUDENT_NUMBER", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("WYEAR_CODE", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 2021;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("WCAMPUS_CODE", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("WCOURSE_CODE", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("WSECTION_CODE", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("WLECTURE_TYPE", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("_PER_TYPE", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = 5;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("v_Return", OracleDbType.RefCursor, 100).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    msg = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
    con.Close();
    return new JsonResult(msg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw (ex);
}
```

and this procedure from Oracle:

[image]

I was expecting such a result:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: You're not using neither Linq nor EF here. Could you try to change `_PER_TYPE` by `PER_TYPE` there is no underscore in the Oracle procedure.

Comment: `cmd.CommandText = "my procedure";`  Are you really allowed whitespace in there?

Comment: @Fildor I delete it

Comment: @McNets I chang it put not work